# PHP GraphQL Syntax error issuing a query using file_get_contents

Tags: php, graphql, file-get-contents

I'm trying to develop a simple php client and I have some trouble.
My code is this:

```
    $Tok = 'my token';
    $Url = 'the api endpoint url';
    $ItemId = '$book - 093121'; // This is the id I search for
    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $Tok];
    $query = 'query product("id":"$ItemId")';
    $data = file_get_contents($Url, false, stream_context_create([
     'http' => [
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => $headers,
      'content' => json_encode(['query' => $query]),
     ]
    ]));
    $responseContent = json_decode($data, true);
    echo json_encode($responseContent);
```

running the script I receive the following:
`{"errors":[{"message":"Line 1 col 18: Syntax error"}]}`

Of course I tryed many combination (with no quotes on 'id' and/or on $ItemID and the result is always the same, maybe with a differnt "col"

The documentation released by the API developer says:

```
query product($id: IdInput!) {
  product(id: $id) {
    id
    ts
    visible
    title
    slug
    description
    stock
    allocated
    price
    productClass
    codiceIva
    discount
    weight
    details {
      ...ProductDetailFragment
    }
  }
}

Variables
{"id": IdInput}
```

I Even tryied with

```
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer $Tok";
    $ch = curl_init($Url);  // inizializza l'oggetto con l'URL da utilizzare
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['query' => $query]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result !== false) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
//      echo json_decode($result);
    }
    else
        echo curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

With the same result.

The json encoded string looks like this:

> {"query":"query product("id":"$book - 093121")"}

And the column 18 corresponds to the "d" befre the backslash

Could someone give me an help?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Start with a simple `echo $query;`, and see what value you actually put in there.

Comment: Hi, the ouput of json_encode is 
`{"query":"query product(\"id\":\"$ItemId\")"}`
Column 18 is the "d"

Comment: Basics: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Sorry @CBroe but I do not understand your comment
The original query is: query product("id":"$ItemId") and the above is the result of the json_encode. Do I miss something?

Comment: Do you want the _literal text_ `$ItemId` in there ...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty tired and I made a mistake posting.
The json output is `{"query":"query product(\"id\":\"$book - 093121\")"}`
where $book - 093121 is the ID of the object I'm searching (this customer has any id formatted like this).

Comment: Do the quotes around `id` belong in there?

Comment: As I said in the first post, I've trued several combination, with and without quotes, but the result is almost the same.
I think in more a GraphicQl problem.
I'm brand new to this API interfce.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the right syntax:

```
{
  "query": "query product($id: IdInput!) {
    product(id: $id) {
      id ts visible title slug description stock allocated price productClass codiceIva discount weight
    }
  }
  ","
  variables ":{"
  id ":"
  $book - 093121 "}
}
```

Where "id, ts, visible ...etc" are the fields to get from the query (like in an SQL query)